# Do I need to add myself to the crontab group for cron to execute my user crontab?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cron, groups

I am running Ubuntu server 9.10, and I am trying to set up some commands in my crontab. However, it seems that none of these commands are executed. I have noticed that there is a crontab group. Do I need to be a member of this group in order for cron to like me?

Comment: Does anything show up in the logs? Do you get anything in your email? Show an example of your crontab entries.

Comment: Gah. I tried to view my crontab with `crontab -e`, but the E and R keys are right next to each other. Time to figure out where my crontab actually resides so I can restore it from backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to be a member of the cron group to run cronjobs, just debug the commands you are trying to run.

Comment: I just realized that my script relies on $PATH being set. And trivial other cron entries run just fine.

Comment: Actually, my script relied on `$PERL5LIB` being set, because my cronjob bash script calls a perl script that relies on some perl modules that are installed my my home directory. It's hard to remember what features depend on your environment.